# What is the phrase used as a label on the food container to convey "No sugar added"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, phrase-requests

I am looking for a pure fruit juice without sugar added for daily consumption in Japan. The box only says 100% bla bla bla but I am not sure whether or not there is sugar added.

So my question is:

> What is the most commonly used Japanese phrase to convey "No sugar
>   added"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you will want to the already suggested phrases but if you are talking about *juice* specifically, you will want to use 「果汁100%」as it doesn't make sense to talk about added sugars in juices. If that were the case, then you would just indicate the percentage of real fruit juice e.g. 果汁30%, which means that the rest of the drink consists of sugar water, etc.

Comment: Exactly what I thought upon reading the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is 砂糖が入っていない or 無糖.

Comment: How about [砂糖不使用](http://blog-imgs-37.fc2.com/r/y/u/ryuusasiotuki/IMG_9431.jpg)?

Comment: Why would you think they would use a lengthy "sentence" like 「砂糖が入っていない」 on a label?

Answer (score 2):

ノンシュガー and [シュガーレス](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9) are also common.

Comment: There's [糖類]{とうるい}ゼロ, too.